# UIDatePicker issue on UITextField(s)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am coding a TableViewController with a Section called Information where the user enter a name , a date , a description. My problem is that after i've done all the settings for the NSDate picker on the date's textfield , when i click on the description's textfield instead of keyboard i see the date picker and it stores date in the date's textfield.

**.h file**

```
@interface ViewControllerInfo : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>{
NSDate *date;
UIActionSheet *dateSheet;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *scadenza;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dateTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSDate *date;

-(void)setDatario;
-(void)dismissDateSet;
-(void)cancelDate;
```

**.m file** (pointing only the functions needed):

```
-(void)setDatario;{

dateSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil      destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

[dateSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0);

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

[dateSheet addSubview:datePicker];

UIToolbar *controlToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, dateSheet.bounds.size.width, 44)];

[controlToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[controlToolbar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *setButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDateSet)];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelDate)];

[controlToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, setButton, cancelBtn, nil] animated:NO];


[dateSheet addSubview:controlToolbar];

[dateSheet showInView:self.view];

[dateSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

}

-(void)cancelDate{

[dateSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

}

-(void)dismissDateSet{

NSArray *listofViews = [dateSheet subviews];

for (UIView *subview in listofViews){
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIDatePicker class]]){
        self.date = [(UIDatePicker*)subview date];

}

    [dateSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

[dateTextField setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.date]];

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
[self setDatario];
return NO;
}
```

I couldn't understand why is interesting also the description's texfield.
Question is : why the description's textfield is matched with the datepicker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your textFieldShouldBeginEditing method like this

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if (textField == scadenza) {

        return YES;
    }
    else if(textField == scadenza){

        [self setDatario];

        return NO;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: if (textfield == self.dateTextField) { [self setDatario]; return YES; } else if(textField == self.scadenza) { return NO; }  that way is perfect! Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

Even better, put a custom `UIButton` (invisible) of the same size as the textfield right over the textfield.  Set the textfield `enabled` attribute to `NO` and then show the picker when the button is tapped.  When the user selects a date from the picker, update the text in the textfield.  This way you won't have to manage the textfield's `delegate`.  I have used both methods and the button is much cleaner and smoother for the user.